# Copy_to_user problems

Tags: device-driver, kernel-module

I wrote module for a device, and I'm having problems in my read function:

```
ssize_t my_sys_read(struct file *f, char __user *buffer, size_t s, loff_t *off){

    char * myBuffer = "ossec buffer";
    size_t read_bytes;

    if (s > ( sizeof(char) * 13 ) ) s = ( sizeof(char) * 13 );

    if (!access_ok(%VERIFY_WRITE, (void *) buffer, s)) return -EFAULT;
        read_bytes = copy_to_user((void *) buffer, (void *) myBuffer, s);

    printk(KERN_INFO "myBuffer %s", myBuffer);
    printk(KERN_INFO "buffer %s", buffer);

    read_bytes = s - ( sizeof(char) * 13 );

    return read_bytes;
```

}

I really don't know why but the copy it's not working, and the printed buffer has no sense for me.

```
 [10038.885838] buffer \xffffff81\xffffffc3\xffffffcb\x1a
```

I guess the problem is in the copy because the program which use the device is simple.

```
int main(void)
  {
    int fd = open(device_name, O_RDONLY);
    if(fd < 0)
    {
      printf("Error: Impossible to open device, action not permited.\n");
      return 0;
    }

    char * buff;
    int read_bytes;
    read_bytes = read(fd, buff, (13 * sizeof(char) ) );

    printf(" %s\n", buff);


  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
char * buff;
int read_bytes;
read_bytes = read(fd, buff, (13 * sizeof(char) ) );
```

You are using the pointer buff without allocating memory for it, it is then a dangling pointer with a random value. You need to do

`char *buff = new char();` or

```
  char buff;
  int read_bytes;
  read_bytes = read(fd, &buff, (13 * sizeof(char)) );
```

Comment: I've already tried it but then I have this error from the module before it returns:
    [12650.165665] testDevice[6812]: segfault at 6573736f ip 003b9e29 sp bf805ce0 error 4 in libc-2.15.so[375000+1a3000]

Comment: You need some kind of call stack, or read the kernel log to have more detailed information about the segfault error. I have no idea what the problem is just reading this error line.

Comment: I have some problems with the buffer, when it returns to the user program, there's problems to printf, segmentation fault.

Comment: Well, I answered your question and you didn't vote for it neither did you accept the answer. And I see that you didn't accept any answer on your other questions in stackoverflow, that's not very fair play. Did you check if "buff" contains anything before you try to printf it? You could try to debug and step through your program to see it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't vote your answer because I need 15 of reputations and I didn't accepted your answer because It does not really work, somehow you help me but I don't know if I can accept a answer if it doesn't really fix the problem.

Comment: Ok, I forgot about that. Did you check the return value of read(fd, buff, (13 * sizeof(char) ) ); ?